# NDP neighbor advertisement windows 10

Tags: c++, windows, sockets, ipv6, icmp

Is it possible to receive NA in application (admin privilegies) on Windows 10?

I can send Neighbor Solicitation to Unicast address but I am unable to obtain any response back. Wireshark shows that packets are transmitted over the network correctlly and are, in response, targeted directly to my IPv6 address and still my socket is not able to receive them.

Because I am able to send message out I'm expecting that my socket is created correctly (AF_INET6, SOCK_RAW, IPPROTO_ICMPV6). I bind it to local address obtained by getaddrinfo with AI_PASSIVE flag. Anyway it should be bound to correct adress when I am sending solicitation, right?

There are some similar questions already, but no one is answered and they are already dated also...